# Add to cart button not working, Selenium C# element not interactable

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I am automating below website, Add to cart button is not working:
http://automationpractice.com

Please use below id pass to login:
ID        : paul@xmail.com
Password  : Pass123##

```
    By addCartTshirt = By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'Add to cart')]");

    public void Add_To_Cart_T_Shirt()
    {
        driver.FindElement(addCartTshirt).Click();
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the more detail, add to cart button at which place is not working? What error are you getting ?

Comment: I selected WOMEN from menu then TOPS then T-SHIRTS, from there i am adding it to cart, but getting error element not interactable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use action method to do it, I checked the below in `Java` and it's working for me.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);

element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//img[@title='Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts']"))

action.moveToElement(element).perform();

ele = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[@title='Add to cart']"));

action.moveToElement(ele).click().perform();
```

do not forget to import

```
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions
```

Comment: @Developer - If your issue is solved, than please accept the answer.